# Media does not find in css

Tags: css

I am working on css.I have used @media in css but there is an error occuring that media does not exist in the current context.How can i solve this problem?

```
@media ( max-width : 585px ) {

        .wizard {
            width: 90%;
            height: auto !important;
        }

        span.round-tab {
            font-size: 16px;
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            line-height: 50px;
        }

        .wizard .nav-tabs > li a {
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            line-height: 50px;
        }

        .wizard li.active:after {
            content: " ";
            position: absolute;
            left: 35%;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you specify where you are seeing this error ?

Comment: Please give sample of code where you are facing this error so that we can debug.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace this line:

```
@media (max-width:585px) {
```

with this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:585px) {
```